# load different apache module based on apache version with one config include?

Tags: apache, apache2, apache2.2, apache-modules

I want to have a config block (in an included file) that will LoadModule different files depending on apache version.

e.g.

```
<some kind of magic detecting apache 2.2>
LoadModule  my_module /usr/local/my/module22.so

<else if apache 2.4>
LoadModule  my_module /usr/local/my/module24.so
<end magic>
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

The longer version of my question:  I have an apache module that I build both 22 and 24 versions of.  On production servers, both modules are installed.  I do not have control over which version of apache is run nor over the startup options (thus eliminating  directives).

I have a small config stub file that gets included by the  main config file that has, approximately:

```
LoadModule my_module /usr/local/my/module22.so

<IfModule my_module>
..... some config stuff that is valid for either version
</IfModule>
```

The module itself is source-code compatible with both versions of apache, but i have to have different binaries since the module api is not binary compatible.

Most servers use 2.2, and a few use 2.4, all out side my control.  I'd like the right thing to happen automatically, but I have not found a way yet.  Whatever I do, it needs to be syntax-compatible with both 2.2 and 2.4.  Ideas?

Or, is there some other way to

Comment: Seems like I might be able to: <IfModule some22onlymodulue...>  If I could find a module that I'm quite sure will only be there for 22 and another for 24 - anyone have a list of default modules for 22 and 24?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is available in apache directives: [IfVersion](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/fr/mod/mod_version.html#ifversion)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Some days google searching, you win, some days you loose.  Hopefully my loss will lead others to this page and they'll win.

Comment: Yes, we'll need some `google search 101` on computer sciences course :-)